# Error with free function after malloc

Tags: c++, malloc, free, beginthread

The code below results in a crash of C++ on the line: **free(arg)**. I am trying to prevent a memory leak from happening but i can't manage to free the data i stored in heap memory. Can someone help me with this problem?

Note that **free(args)** works fine.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    int StartNode;
    int EndNode;
}t;
t *arg;

void myFunc(void *param) {
    t *args = (t*)param;
    int x = args->StartNode;
    int y = args->EndNode;
    printf("x=%d, y=%d\n", x, y);
    free(args);
    free(arg);
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE handle;
    arg = (t *)malloc(sizeof(t));
    arg->StartNode = 101;
    arg->EndNode = 103;
    handle = (HANDLE)_beginthread(myFunc, 0, (void*)arg);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like `args` and `arg` point to the same allocation. You're freeing it twice.

Comment: By the way, can I talk you into using `new`? A Smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` should be appropriate here as well.

Comment: It seems you are totally right, when i comment the line: free(args), the free(arg) works fine. I'll look into your suggestion, i am a bit new to pointers so i'll have to try it out a little more. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) next time

Comment: As you pass in the parameter as function argument anyway, there is no need at all for the global variable...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your both pointers respectively `args` and `arg` are pointing to the same memory location and you are trying to release same memory location twice, and that creating the issue here. Please see below:-

```
 free(args); //args->arg here args is pointing to arg you have just type cast it from void
 free(arg);//you have already release the memory in the above call so this is wrong
```

Just try like this for understanding, below example is not a solution but for your understanding. Here you assign `args = NULL` and that will be reflected in `arg = NULL` hence `if(arg != NULL)` will be false and hence `free(arg);` will not be call.:-

```
free(args); 
args = NULL;
if(arg != NULL)
  free(arg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both args and arg are pointing to same memory location. Calling free on any one should be enough.

Answer (score -2):

The number of free calls needs to be the same as malloc.
you malloc the conde only once, in

```
arg = (t *)malloc(sizeof(t));
```

but you free the same address twice:

```
free(args);
free(arg);
```

Now, this is C code, not C++ (as C++ you would use new / delete, or even better, you would *not* use nor new nor delete, and pass the variables via reference in the stack like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

struct MyType {
    int StartNode;
    int EndNode;
};

void myFunc(const MyType &param) {
    const auto x = args.StartNode;
    const auto y = args.EndNode;
    std::cout << "x=" << x << ", y=" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto arg = MyType{};
    arg.StartNode = 101;
    arg.EndNode = 103;
    std::thread thread(myFunc, arg);
    thread.join();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Some random notes:

- you are mixing C with C++, they are *not* the same language
- you are using windows-only calls, use std (like in the thread example)
- don't use using namespace std; this makes code unreadable in no time.